# In sublime text 3 while using mingw for c_++, I am getting this errorThe system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, mingw

Following is the error I am facing:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
    [Finished in 9.7s with exit code 1]
    [cmd: ['g++.exe', '-std=c++17', 'C:\\Users\\D Tawar\\Desktop\\Code\\new.cpp', '-o', 'new.exe', '&&', 'new.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in']]
    [dir: C:\Users\D Tawar\Desktop\Code]
    [path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\bin]
```

Comment: So look at your system at the various files that your command requires e.g. `C:\Users\D Tawar\Desktop\Code\new.cpp` and `new.exe` and `inputf.in` and report back which ones you can find, and which you cannot.

Comment: Looking carefully, it seems that you have set your build command to look for the file `new.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in`. Obviously that is a mistake.

Comment: @john can you elaborate the mistake

Comment: I don't know sublime text, but it seems to be a quotation mistake. You meant to run the command `new.exe <inputf.in >outputf.in`, iei you meant to execute a program called `new.exe` with two redirections `<inputf.in` and `>outputf.in` but because of the quotation mistake you ended up asking for a program called `new.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in` to be executed. Instead of treating `<inputf.in` and `>outputf.in` as separate parts of the command they are being treated as part of the filename of the program you want to run. Obviously this results in a file not found error.

Comment: @john thanks my problem solved.

Comment: @john can you write that up as an answer? This question comes up periodically, and I'd love to have a good dupe target to point people to.

Comment: @MattDMo It was just an educated guess, and I know nothing about sublime text so I don't feel confident writing a proper answer.